# Как писать производные от названия команды?

Tags: кавычки

Есть футбольная команда "Рубин". Их нередко называют "рубиновцами". Нужны ли в данном случае кавычки?

Или еще один пример: в правоохранительных органах есть специализированная команда "Носорог". Людей, которые работают в этой команде, называют "носорогами". Нужны ли и здесь кавычки, если слово по сути стало нарицательным в рамках службы (хотя могу и ошибаться)?

> — Вчера рубиновцы выиграли матч!

> — Сегодня носорогов видел, — сказал Андрей. — Опять им новое задание
> подкинули.

Comment: Это не те, что гонщиков ловят?

Comment: @oleedd пример был выдуман из головы (в рамках какой-нибудь художественной книги).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Особого правила на этот счет нет. Здесь, видимо, можно ориентироваться на правило названия жителей, образованные от географических названий, напр.: петербуржцы, ньюйоркцы, ставропольчане, волжане (Академический справочник).

Да и в словарях *см.напр. орфографический словарь Лопатина), такие названия пишутся со строчной. [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/), также здесь. [см. в словаре](https://academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86)

Что касается кавычек. Грамота.ру пишет, что в кавычки в публицистических текстах не ставятся. Данные Национального корпуса  это подтверждают.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Подобное словообразование регулярно встречается в той же классической литературе (лень искать), например (как минимум по 10 слов на книгу), то есть когда есть в языке словообразовательная возможность посредством добавления морфемы, но слово потом не выглядит как какая-то литературная норма. Такие слова нигде не выделяются кавычками.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ